# Changing Channel Name in an iFrame SRC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to embed a Twitch stream inside of my website with the ability to change the channel using some text input and a button. Below is my failed attempt at this project. I apologize in advance I am very new to coding and I've got a long way to go. How would I fix what I have to accomplish my goal?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="newtwitchchannel">

<button type="button" onclick="function()">Change Channel</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var oldSrc = $("#SamplePlayerDivID iframe").attr("src");
        var x = document.getElementById("myText");
        var currentVal = x.value;
        var newSrc = oldSrc.replace("channel=monstercat", "channel=+current Val"); "autoplay=1" by "+current Val"
        
        $("#SamplePlayerDivID iframe").attr("src", newSrc);
        
        console.log("Old Src: " + oldSrc);
        console.log("New Src: " + newSrc);
      });
      
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SamplePlayerDivID">
  <iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=monstercat&muted=true" frameborder="0" style="height: 480; width: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `</script>` tag.

Comment: You're defining `newSrc` wrong. And if you're always replacing the same string (monstercat), you won't be able to change the string after it's been changed once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="newtwitchchannel">

<button type="button" onclick="changeChannel()">Change Channel</button>

<script>
function changeChannel() {
    var oldSrc = $("#SamplePlayerDivID iframe").attr("src");
    var x = document.getElementById("myText");
    var currentVal = x.value;
    var newSrc = oldSrc.replace("channel=monstercat", "channel=" + currentVal);

    $("#SamplePlayerDivID iframe").attr("src", newSrc);

    console.log("Old Src: " + oldSrc);
    console.log("New Src: " + newSrc);
}   
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SamplePlayerDivID">
  <iframe src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=monstercat&muted=true" frameborder="0" style="height: 480; width: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I changed:

- no need to wrap in `$(document).ready()`. Converted your code into a standalone function called `changeChannel()`.
- change the `onClick` attribute of the `button` to call `changeChannel()`.
- syntax error in the `oldSrc.replace()` call. Check out how I'm concatenating strings in my example compared to yours.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm I appreciate your help Lee!